# Finding file name using regex from glob

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, glob

I have directory with files as follows.

- test.[8 random alphanumeric characters].js
- test.[8 random alphanumeric characters].[10 random alphanumeric characters].js

I want to find the file test.[8 random alphanumeric characters].js using glob.

When do the following it returns both files.

```
from glob import glob

glob(BASEDIR + '/test.*.js')
```

and when I do the following it returns an empty array.

```
from glob import glob

glob(BASEDIR + '/test.[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}.js')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regex solution:

```
import os
import re
res=[i for i in os.listdir(BASEDIR) if re.match(r'test\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\.js',i)]
print(res)
```

NOTE: the solution would just be the name of file, you can use

```
os.join(BASEDIR,res[i])
```

to get full path